# UNIX: Using sed, how to print every 1st and 2nd lines in sets of 4 lines?

Tags: unix, sed

My file has multiple sets of lines. Each set has 4 lines. Line 1-4 is set 1. Line 5-8 is set 2 and so on. I need to print the first two lines from every set i.e line 1 and 2, line 5 and 6 and so on.

File content:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
..
line n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n '1~4p;2~4p'
```

`1~4p` matches every 4th line, starting with the 1st:

```
line 1
line 5
line 9
…
```

`2~4p` matches every 4th line, starting with the 2nd:

```
line 2
line 6
line 10
…
```

When used together, they do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for new info: I'd not come across `m~n` before, mainly because it's not in this otherwise [excellent tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html).

Comment: thank you for the answer. Exactly what I needed. My mac bash terminal didn't recognize ~. It ran fine on git bash on windows. After, I was able to figure out why mac bash didn't work.

Comment: @kabitaregmi Consider accepting my answer to indicate the problem is solved. Please see our [tour] for details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `sed` is the tool of choice here - why not just shell-script it?

```
cat /path/to/infile | while true; do read l || break ; echo "$l" ; read l || break ; echo "$l" ; read l || break ; read l || break ; done > /path/to/outfile
```

Comment: I was going to propose a similar answer, but you need to use a variant of the `read` command in order to avoid changes to the line: `read -r l` will avoid special processing (eg back-slashes on the line), but leading and trailing blanks will be lost. What you need is `read -r` with no variable, which reads the line, including all blanks into `$REPLY", so you use `echo "$REPLY"` instead of `echo "$l"`.

Comment: thank you for your answer too. I knew looping would work. I needed to do with sed.